# android studio dimension not referring properly

Tags: android, android-studio, reference

I have installed android studio on my ubuntu system and I am creating the layout file like below.I am using ConstraintLayout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_material"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/normal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_social_person"
    app:border_color="@android:color/white"
    app:border_width="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/most_most_normal_margin"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="Arjith"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/profile_pic"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_pic" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and i have updated dimen.xml file like below.

```
 <resources>   
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="profile_img_size">80dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="most_most_most_min_margin">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_most_min_margin">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_min_margin">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="min_margin">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_most_most_normal_margin">13dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_most_normal_margin">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_normal_margin">17dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="normal_margin">20dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="most_most_most_min_padding">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_most_min_padding">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_min_padding">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="min_padding">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_most_most_normal_padding">13dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_most_normal_padding">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="most_normal_padding">17dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="normal_padding">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I have referred CircleImageView width and height with @dimen/profile_img_size. but, it remains until I am rotating the preview screen. Then, it's changed back to 80dp. It is not referring to the dimen.xml file. Other than this, other dimension referring is working properly. I tried invalidating the cache, do did a system restart. Nothing seems to work. Help will be appreciated. You may also check  screenshots here:

[image: dimen] 
[image: xmllayout]

thank you again.